# Which hibernate adapter should I use to handle Lazy Initialization in BlazeDS / Spring integration projects with Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, hibernate, spring, blazeds

I'm researching ways in which the Spring Framework, Hibernate and BlazeDS can play happily together without throwing lazy initialization exceptions.

So far, I ran across Gilead, dpHibernate and an entirely different alternative implementation of this problem via GraniteDS's Tide framework.

Aside from GraniteDS, there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation on either properly integrating dpHibernate or Gilead.

Are there alternative libraries that solve this problem? Where can I find better guides of integrating these lazy loading libraries with the Spring-Flex integration project?

Answer (score 1):

I usually translate my entities into DTOs and then transfer those.

Answer (score 1):

I see this question is a couple years old, but I'm going to answer with hopes it helps someone stumbling across this from google:

Take a look at [dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/). As much as I loathe DTOs, it's a nice system for mapping your Entity Objects to DTOs with control over what gets copied.

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much covered the available options. I personally lean towards Tide because it just seems like the most solid option and works independently of GraniteDS.

Comment: Are you saying you can use Tide with BlazeDS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Gilead on my current project and it works very well once it has been configured properly. This configuration can be found on gilead project website. If all works well, you should have Gilead up and running in no time. I can't speak for the other frameworks though but with Gilead you don't need to adapt your javabeans or your services or whatever. Just a simple configuration in remoting-services.xml